# SQL cursor variable can not use in conditions

Tags: sql, cursor

any idea why my @ProductNumber cursor variable is not working if used in dynamic statement?  It says "Must declare scalar variable".  But this is a cursor variable.  But when I used it not dynamic, it works.  Thanks.

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DateEffectiveFrom datetime
DECLARE @InsertRecords NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @TargetDB = 'MySSISDb'
SET @SourceDB = 'MySSISDb2'
SET @DateEffectiveFrom = '2013-12-29'

Declare @ProductNumber INT;
DECLARE @SqlDb NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CAST(@SqlDb AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SET @SqlDb = 'SELECT ProductNumber From '+@SourceDB+'.dbo.Item (NOLOCK)
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '+@TargetDB+'.dbo.Item2 
                 WHERE ProductNumber   = '+@SourceDB+'.dbo.Item.ProductNumber)'
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlDb

OPEN Cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ProductNumber;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @InsertRecords = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.Item2(
                           ProductNumber,   ProductName, ListPrice, BirthDate) 
             SELECT ProductNumber, ProductName, 
                ListPrice, ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(25),@DateEffectiveFrom,120) + '''
         FROM ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item
         WHERE ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item.ProductNumber = @ProductNumber'

--WHERE ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item.ProductNumber = @ProductNumber 
--(this is where the     problem)

EXEC sp_executesql @InsetRecords

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ProductNumber;
END
CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the declaration of your cursor into the SQLDb variable. In SQL Server, at least, the cursor designation "Cur1" is accessible after the execution of @SQLDb. Also, I've moved the use of @ProductNumber to outside the literal string and fixed a typo on your second EXEC statement within the cursor while loop (@InsetRecords to @InsertRecords).

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DateEffectiveFrom datetime
DECLARE @InsertRecords NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @TargetDB = 'MySSISDb'
SET @SourceDB = 'MySSISDb2'
SET @DateEffectiveFrom = '2013-12-29'

Declare @ProductNumber INT;
DECLARE @SqlDb NVARCHAR(Max)

SET @SqlDb = '
  DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ProductNumber 
    From '+@SourceDB+'.dbo.Item (NOLOCK)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM '+@TargetDB+'.dbo.Item2 
      WHERE ProductNumber   = '+@SourceDB+'.dbo.Item.ProductNumber)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlDb

OPEN Cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ProductNumber;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @InsertRecords = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.Item2(
                           ProductNumber,   ProductName, ListPrice, BirthDate) 
             SELECT ProductNumber, ProductName, 
                ListPrice, ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(25),@DateEffectiveFrom,120) + '''
         FROM ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item
         WHERE ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item.ProductNumber = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @ProductNumber)

EXEC sp_executesql @InsertRecords

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ProductNumber;
END

CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;
```

Comment: Thanks Zec!  Your help is really appreciated.  I tested it, it seems going to work except for minor error -                             Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'INSERT INTO MySSISDb.dbo.Item2(ProductNumber,   ProductName, ListPrice, BirthDate) 
             SELECT ProductNumber, ProductName, ListPrice, ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(25),@DateEffectiveFrom,120) + '''
         FROM MySSISDb.dbo.Item
         WHERE MySSISDb.dbo.Item.ProductNumber = ' to data type int.

Comment: Ah, yes. I assumed it would convert the ProductNumber variable to a string implicitly as part of the concatenation. Probably a bit lazy of me regardless. See how I've converted the ProductNumber variable explicitly. I've just used nvarchar(max) as I'm not sure how long a product number may be in this context.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a lot @Zec.. I really appreciate your help.  Sometimes, I am hesitant to ask here at StackOverflow as other members are quite rude. As you know, I am trying to google, read books, research, etc. that will answer my problem, but doing it alone is quite hard.  I still believe that programming is "Pair Programming".  Thanks a lot.  God bless you.